# java.lang.StackOverflowError on Drawable.draw

Tags: android, stack-overflow

When using Custom Class show a pic on TextView,
I use spanned to show A NetImage on TextView, \
code like Below

```
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(string, new NetImageGetter(mContext, holderNormal.tv_content),
                    new NetTagHandler(mContext));
            holderNormal.tv_content.setText(spanned);
```

NetImageGetter like below:

```
public class NetImageGetter implements ImageGetter {

private Context context;
private TextView tv;
private int height;

public NetImageGetter(Context context, TextView tv) {
    this.context = context;
    this.tv = tv;
    height = CommonUtil.dip2px(context, 18);
    if (height == 0) {
        height = 36;
    }
}

@Override
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    // 将source进行MD5加密并保存至本地
    String imageName = Common.md5(source);
    String rootPath = QikeApplication.mCacheNeedClearDir; // 获取SDCARD的路径
    // 获取图片后缀名
    String[] ss = source.split("\\.");
    String ext = ss[ss.length - 1];

    // 最终图片保持的地址
    String savePath = rootPath + "/" + imageName + "." + ext;

    File file = new File(savePath);
    if (file.exists()) {
        // 如果文件已经存在，直接返回
        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(savePath);
        if (drawable != null) {
            int picHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
            int picWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, ((int) (height / picHeight * picWidth)), height);
            return drawable;
        }
    }

    // 不存在文件时返回默认图片，并异步加载网络图片
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    URLDrawable drawable = new URLDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
    new ImageAsync(drawable).execute(savePath, source);
    return drawable;

}

private class ImageAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Drawable> {

    private URLDrawable drawable;

    public ImageAsync(URLDrawable drawable) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
        String savePath = params[0];
        String url = params[1];

        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            // 获取网络图片
            HttpGet http = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) client.execute(http);
            BufferedHttpEntity bufferedHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity());
            in = bufferedHttpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                if (in != null)
                    in.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
            }
        }

        if (in == null)
            return drawable;

        try {
            File file = new File(savePath);
            String basePath = file.getParent();
            File basePathFile = new File(basePath);
            if (!basePathFile.exists()) {
                basePathFile.mkdirs();
            }
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fileout.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            fileout.flush();

            Drawable mDrawable = Drawable.createFromPath(savePath);
            return mDrawable;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return drawable;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            drawable.setDrawable(result);
            tv.setText(tv.getText()); // 通过这里的重新设置 TextView 的文字来更新UI
        }
    }

}

public class URLDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {

    private Drawable drawable;

    public URLDrawable(Drawable defaultDraw) {
        setDrawable(defaultDraw);
    }

    private void setDrawable(Drawable nDrawable) {
        drawable = nDrawable;
        int picHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int picWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        if (picWidth != 0) {
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, ((int) (height / picHeight * picWidth)), height);
            setBounds(0, 0, ((int) (height / picHeight * picWidth)), height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        try {
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

And use it on a adapter
run normal,but on some phone type, throw a StackOverflowError on

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.telecast.library.util.NetPicTextView.NetImageGetter$URLDrawable.draw(NetImageGetter.java:166)
```

I write a try catch,but useless. 
Someone can help me?

Comment: You say on some phone types it throws a `StackOverflowError`... Which type(s) are those? Which devices (if any) don't exhibit this behavior?

Comment: I don't exactly know which devices, I know these exceptions on statistics plug-in, maybe on some low configuration devices. maybe this cost to much RAM?